# Reduce returning redundant solutions

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

When I call reduce on the following system:

```
polys={-x13 x14 x45, x13 x14 x38, x13 x14 x39 - x13 x14 x46 + x14 x26 x79, 
 x13 x14 x27, x14^2 x27 - x14^2 x58, 
 x14 x15 x27 + x14 x28 x45 + x17 x38 x45 - x14 x15 x58 - x15 x45 x58, 
 x14 x16 x27 + x15 x26 x27 + x14 x28 x46 + x17 x38 x46 - x13 x14 x48 -
   x14 x16 x58 - x15 x46 x58 - x13 x38 x79, 
 x14 x17 x27 + x15 x27^2 - x14^2 x59, 
 x14 x18 x27 + x15 x27 x28 + x13 x17 x38 + x16 x27 x38 + x14 x28 x48 +
   x17 x38 x48 + x15 x28 x58 + x18 x38 x58 - x14 x15 x59 - 
  x15 x45 x59, 
 x14 x19 x27 + x15 x27 x29 + x13 x17 x39 + x16 x27 x39 - x13 x14 x49 +
   x14 x28 x49 + x17 x38 x49 - x14 x16 x59 + x15 x28 x59 + 
  x18 x38 x59 - x15 x46 x59 - x13 x17 x79 + x14 x29 x79 - 
  x13 x39 x79 + x17 x39 x79, x27 x38 x45, x27 x38 x46 - x14 x26 x58, 
 x26 x27 x38 + x27 x38 x48 + x28 x38 x58, 
 x26 x27 x39 + x27 x38 x49 - x14 x26 x59 + x28 x38 x59 + x27 x39 x79, 
 x38^2 x58, x38^2 x59, x26 x27 x45, x27^2 x45, 
 x27 x28 x45 + x27 x38 x46 + x28 x45 x58 + x38 x48 x58, 
 x27 x29 x45 + x27 x39 x46 + x28 x45 x59 + x38 x48 x59 - x13 x27 x79, 
 x38 x58^2, x38 x58 x59, x14 x45 x58 - x45^2 x58, 
 x14 x46 x58 - x45 x46 x58, x14 x48 x58 + x15 x58^2 - x45^2 x59, 
 x14 x49 x58 - x45 x46 x59 + x15 x58 x59 + x14 x59 x79, x45 x58^2, 
 x45 x58 x59};

red=Reduce[polys==0];
```

The result contains some redundant solutions, for example:

```
red[[5]]
red[[21]]
(*x79 == 0 && x59 == 0 && x58 == 0 && x39 == 0 && x38 == 0 && x27 == 0 && x14 == 0*)
(*x79 == 0 && x59 == 0 && x58 == 0 && x39 == 0 && x38 == 0 && x27 == 0 && x14 == 0 && x45 != 0*)
```

How can I obtain the most general form for the solution set?

Comment: Remove those results using Assumptionts. You can write `Reduce[polys==0, Assumptions -> x79!=0&&x59!=0&&etc]`

Comment: There are other redundant solutions so that would require going through all of them manually

Comment: what is your notion of redundant? This seems more like a math question rather than a software question

Comment: By redundant I mean that x45 can be 0 or nonzero and we still get a solution so ```(*x79 == 0 && x59 == 0 && x58 == 0 && x39 == 0 && x38 == 0 && x27 == 0 && x14 == 0*)``` is the output I would expect

Comment: So I guess my real question is how to get the most general solution(s) to a system of polynomials. (I thought reduce would do this)